# Тире и двоеточие в бессоюзном сложном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Какой знак препинания вы поставите в скобках?

> Я не мог долго оставаться на одном месте (: - ) меня грызла тоска.
>
> А углубляться мы не могли  ( :-) земля примерзла.

Comment: А вообще-то мы уже об этом говорили:http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/26338/%D0

Comment: Людмила, ссылка ваша не открывается.

Comment: Видимо, технические причины, я же заходила, ссылку сняла. Может, на проекте убирают давние диалоги.

Comment: Не знаю. Вряд ли.

Answer (score 2):

В обоих предложениях вторая часть раскрывает причину того, о чем говорится в первой части, поэтому вполне уместно двоеточие.

Comment: Двоеточие вполне уместно, конечно. Но обратимся к правилам.

У Розенталя: Вариантивны двоеточие и тире в бессоюзных сложных предложениях с причинно следственными связями. 
Напр.: А углубляться мы не могли  (по какой причине?)  - земля примерзла. 
Ср. также: Кажется, Приморью и без того есть чем подивить мир (:-) одни тигры  да женьшень  чего только стоят. Розенталь Д. Э. Справочник-практикум:

Comment: Орфография.Пунктуация.
В бессоюзном сложном предложении при обозначении пояснения, причины, обоснования, изъяснения допустимо употребление тире вместо двоеточия (особенно в художественной литературе и в публицистике). Пр.: На молу погасили огни — теплоход ушел; В армию меня тоже не берут — сердце заштопанное.
Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина.

Comment: Я не мог долго оставаться на одном месте (: - ) меня грызла тоска. Это предложение из теста. Там двоеточие. Я обращался на Грамма.ру ( откуда собственно тест). Пришел ответ. Ответили то же, что и вы. Но я потом правило, согласно которым, можно и тире и двоеточие. Меня интересует, как быть в таких случаях. Насколько корректно задание. Может, кто-нибудь из вас сталкивался уже с подобными случаями?

>Грамма.ру еще не ответило.

Comment: Смотря о чём идёт речь. Если это ЕГЭ, нужно отвечать согласно академическим правилам - только двоеточие. Если это просто худ. текст - возможно всё, и править нет смысла, сейчас творческим людям многое позволено, ошибки превратились в худ. средства, у Пушкина бы волосы дыбом встали от поэзии символистов, а уж он-то и сам вольничал немало.

Comment: А вы считаете, что тире не допустимо?

Comment: Допустимо, но вторично,это уже современный подход, а академический - двоеточие. Если это задание на экзамене, умничать и "творить" нет смысла, там проверяют академические знания, в ключах заложены академические справочники. Я с самого начала ЕГЭ готовлю к нему, ещё когда эксперимент был, мы были в пилотном проекте, я это поняла. Раньше вообще было много некорректных заданий, сейчас вроде бы нет, всё нормально.Просто нужно следовать классическим правилам.

Comment: Обратите внимание(по ссылке Славы):Примечание 2. В бессоюзном сложном предложении при обозначении пояснения, причины, обоснования, изъяснения допустимо употребление тире вместо двоеточия . ДОПУСТИМО, т.е. вторично, даже дано в примечаниях, а не в основном правиле.

Answer (score 1):

**Из ПАС** (http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=417#pg417 ):

> **§ 129…**
>
> **Примечание 3.** Двоеточие употребляется в тех синтаксических
> условиях, где может наиболее
> проявиться его
> разъяснительно-пояснительная функция,
> например в двучленных конструкциях с
> именительным падежом в обеих частях,
> которые строятся по схеме: название
> общей проблемы и конкретизирующие ее
> частные детали; место 
> и событие и т. п. **Такие конструкции
> распространены в заголовках, особенно
> в названиях рубрик газет**: *Критика:
> обратная связь; Мировые проблемы: пути
> решения; Александр Блок: неизданное
> наследие; Коммунальная служба: ключи и
> резервы; Телевидение: программа на
> неделю; Высшая школа: еще один взгляд
> на студенческое самоуправление.*
>
> **Примечание 4.** Двоеточие **обязательно в сложных предложениях**, в которых вторая
> часть, пояснительная, представляет
> собой сложноподчиненное предложение:
> *Потом мне стало ясно: чтобы лучше понять людей, надо жить среди них*
> (газ.).

**И ВСЁ !** Во всех же прочих случаях (как Вы сами, Серж, указали) **"при обозначении пояснения, причины, обоснования, изъяснения допустимо употребление тире вместо двоеточия".**

ЭТО "ДОПУСТИМО" ОТНОСИТСЯ И К ПРИВЕДЁННЫМ ВАМИ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯМ.

Comment: Слава, объяснения ПАСА, которое приводите вы, не подходит под этот пример: А углубляться мы не могли (по какой причине?) - земля примерзла. И к этому тоже. Я не мог долго оставаться на одном месте (: - ) меня грызла тоска. В ПАСе, говорится, что допустимо, у Розенталя - вариативность. В любом случае буду ждать ответа от Граммы.ру.

Comment: Серж, ну и что Вам сказала Грамма.ру? Не поделитесь?

Comment: Слава, они мне привели правило, где говорится, что в бессоюзных сложных предложениях с  причинным значением употребляется двоеточие. Но когда я привел правило, где говорится о вариативности тире и двоеточия, ответа не последовало.

Comment: Слава, а сегодня пришел ответ. 
В примере  из справочника под ред. Д. Э. Розенталя МЕЖДУ ЧАСТЯМИ можно 
увидеть ОТНОШЕНИЯ КАК ПОЯСНЕНИЯ, ТАК И ОБОСНОВАНИЯ. "Кажется, Приморью и 
без того есть чем подивить мир ((:) чем именно? и  (-) обоснование) одни 
тигры  да женьшень  чего только стоят". Обратите внимание: постановка 
тире" допустима",  то есть "не обязательна, но возможна".
В нашем конкретном примере причинные отношения более очевидны, чем 
отношения обоснования: "Я не мог долго оставаться на одном месте (по 
какой причине? почему): ПОТОМУ  ЧТО меня грызла тоска".

Comment: Полагаем, что речь идет именно о ДОПУСТИМОСТИ постановки тире вместо 
двоеточия (с чем мы не спорим). Наш пример, кстати, же взят из учебника 
Д.Э. Розенталя. Кроме того,если Вы обратили внимание, в тесте есть 
бесспорный вариант постановки тире.

Answer (score 0):

В первом предложении напрашивается двоеточие, поскольку объясняемая далее причина нестандартна и нужно привлечь к ней внимание (мол, дело вот в чём:). Во втором я бы поставил тире, поскольку названа одна из причин, которые легко предугадать: как будто пропущено "- сами понимаете, что...".

**P.S.** Если делать из этого обобщения, то в первом предложении сказано, *"по какой"* причине, во втором - *"по которой"*.

Comment: Ой, Александр, какая разница - стандартная - нестандартная. Где в правилах такое сказано? Главное - правила допускают.

Comment: Людмила, а справочник Розенталя основан на правилах - 56.

Comment: Людмила, а что за такой ''пилотный проект''?

Comment: У Розенталя всё в порядке,просто его понимают, кому как нравится, надо читать внимательно и всё.Вот у него:
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/51.htm   Примечание. Для разграничения случаев постановки двоеточия и тире в бесс. сл. предл.можно исходить из общего положения:если основная часть высказывания (соответствующая главному предложению ) заключена в первой ч., а во второй содержится пояснение,раскрытие содержания первой части, изложение какого-либо факта, указание на причину, то  ставится двоеточие; если же осн.часть высказывания заключена во второй части, то между частями ставится тире.

Comment: Людмила, я не говорю, что не в порядке.По Розенталю - тире и двоеточие вариативные знаки препинания. А углубляться мы не могли (по какой причине?) - земля примерзла.  

См. Вариативные знаки препинания.

Comment: А пилотный проект - апробация,эксперимент,мы сдавали эти тесты в профильных военных классах, когда ещё даже названия ЕГЭ не было - в 2001/2002 годах.И двоечник написал на 4, а отличник на слабую 3,он с сочинением тужился-пыжился, а двоечник с пятого на десятое, но баллы набрал, и отвечал наобум, методом исключения, а там было несколько правильных ответов, гораздо труднее, чем сейчас.